# Taking quoted variable in a function and making it bare

Tags: r, function

I have a function that calls the lm_robust function from the estimatr package in R. I want to be able to specify a variable on which to cluster standard errors, but the lm_robust function only allows bare (unquoted) variable names in lm_robust's cluster option while my function needs the input to be a quoted variable name.

How do I take a variable that is input into a function (such as "cl") and turn it into a unquoted variable (such as cl)?

Comment: Perhaps `?noquote`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's not about just removing quotes. It's about turning a character value into a symbol and then making sure that symbol gets properly evaluated. Different packages do this in different ways so having an example here to test with would be valuable.

Answer (score 3):

Use `as.name` in `do.call`:

```
library(estimatr)
example(lm_robust)
## ... snip ...

clname <- "clusterID"
do.call("lm_robust", list(y ~ x + z, data = quote(dat), weights = quote(w),
   clusters = as.name(clname)))
```

giving:

```
              Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)  CI Lower  CI Upper
(Intercept)  3.4261621  0.2009692 17.0481986 1.332761e-05  2.908643  3.943681
x           -0.6734741  0.1351184 -4.9843254 4.300590e-03 -1.022076 -0.324872
z            0.5850340  0.9436175  0.6199907 5.566933e-01 -1.689652  2.859720
                  DF
(Intercept) 4.970885
x           4.940162
z           6.396615
```