# Character to unquoted

Tags: r

Sometimes data files come in `.rdata` objects. These are annoying compared to `.rds` files because the objects have predefined names. In my case, I want to rename the object automatically and get rid of the wrongly named version. Simple somewhat contrived example:

```
#make a new iris with a bad name
badnameiris = iris
#save it to a file
save(badnameiris, file = "iris.rdata")
#rename badname version from global envir
rm(badnameiris)
#read iris from file
irisname = load("iris.rdata")
#this variable is not iris, but the name of the variable it was assigned to
irisname
[1] "badnameiris"
#it's to use the right name with get()
goodnameiris = get(irisname)
#but harder to get rid of the wrong one with rm()
rm(irisname)
```

The last line does not work as intended because it requires a bare name as input and it gets a character vector. I realize one can actually use the `list` argument in `rm()`, but suppose one could not.

How does one in general convert from character to unquoted for these purposes?

I tried the **rlang** functions, but these are for non-standard evaluation as used in **tidyverse** context. I tried `as.name()`, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831903/taking-quoted-variable-in-a-function-and-making-it-bare). Does not work either. Most questions I could find asking this question relate to **tidyverse**, but I'm trying to do base R context.

(An alternative solution above is to make a function that utilizes the destruction of the local environment to remove the unwanted copy of the object.)

Comment: That's functionally the same as my last comment in parentheses, but not really what I am asking here.

Comment: rm(list = irisname)

Comment: In general, you could use do.call.

Comment: This question is not about `save()` type functions. Neither is it about `rm(list = x)`, which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use do.call:

```
x <- 1
s <- "x"
do.call(rm, list(s))
ls()
#[1] "s"
```

Or compute on the language:

```
eval(bquote(rm(.(s))))
```